# How to differentiate the type internet connection in React Native iOS?

Tags: react-native

I need to check what kind of connection the iOS device is using at the moment: if it's a Wifi connection or mobile data.

I'm using netinfo library at the moment but so far from what I looked up, seems like it's only possible to check if device connected to internet or not. That's not enough for my solution.

Any work-around is welcome.

Application info:

```
"react-native": "^0.64.0",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `@react-native-community/netinfo` you can also check what type of connection the user is using.

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
console.log("Connection type", state.type);
});
```